# Ticks for Chart with odd style

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to plot some data where the X axis is somehow in bytes. The values grow exponentially, so I scaled them by hand to obtain a better chart. However, I don't want to show the log but the real number and I want to show the numbers with variable unit (byte, Kb, Mb). I am quite close, but I am missing the unit.

```
\documentclass{paper}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[pdftex]{color}

\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shadows,patterns}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{dblfloatfix}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\pgfplotstableread{
{Data Size}    {Shared Memory}   {NIO}
0   1.510618995 1.211303577
1   3.2303486   2.284973183
1.5849625007    4.856564878 3.650475913
2   6.477938316 4.413739735
2.5849625007    9.712070412 7.308872177
3   12.931555487    8.820402778
3.5849625007    19.484353638    12.822872274
3.7004397181    21.122457882    14.851562274
4   25.912743129    18.621127822
4.2479275134    30.729567163    22.179711705
4.3923174228    34.29160211 19.027447421
4.5849625007    38.244025295    29.328904007
4.7548875022    43.959939412    32.568470093
4.8579809951    46.929519191    34.986339417
5   52.492719706    39.106509783
5.1292830169    58.46781981 31.501307665
5.4918530963    73.543666985    43.323522934
5.5849625007    77.459322667    48.490743999
5.672425342 82.985235817    56.872079534
5.9307373376    99.796973815    54.818062952
6   102.283900308   57.550038602
6.0660891905    108.375577493   60.505008949
6.5391588111    148.767633673   83.800438008
6.5849625007    152.995602336   106.139907555
6.6293566201    160.628615581   89.067641012
6.9657842847    200.161297725   112.453472776
7   205.824015933   135.930753075
7.0334230015    210.192513373   116.697242107
7.5622424242    304.035778887   168.699330324
7.5849625007    305.748875502   178.617329882
7.6073303137    314.050317173   223.004631634
7.9829935747    401.791173697   304.945579899
8   409.483432748   303.157529871
8.0168082877    424.119265186   231.545405236
8.5736471875    605.448555176   424.80696054
8.5849625007    607.284603452   342.123641214
8.5961897561    615.863754668   395.555755955
8.9915218461    803.207926285   611.575583119
9   812.506013352   553.18025024
9.0084286221    815.09008592    578.762145252
9.5793159376    1210.628898233  925.793618042
9.5849625007    1209.223171089  683.90157147
9.5905870499    1219.631198049  893.794979677
9.9957671509    1596.264405994  1103.914749616
10  1606.587640249  1085.280140642
10.0042204663   1616.864825222  1130.343164423
10.5821419817   2345.139190349  1528.461298638
10.5849625007   2403.540379252  1430.78942209
10.5877775163   2366.704676255  1456.155914263
10.9978851278   3076.509079427  1803.067395975
11  3078.925940461  1746.102644706
11.0021117765   3111.258074768  1994.433990999
11.5835529305   4556.56852076   3058.174009469
11.5849625007   4502.975871005  2551.424401063
11.5863706951   4538.094725282  2533.045417625
11.9989429514   5827.952659919  4983.721139081
12  5812.588729177  3774.507385952
12.0010562746   5853.675269234  4017.979668263
12.5842578877   8386.555402598  4910.603339731
12.5849625007   8332.804968689  4966.990490482
12.5856667697   8392.878076465  5048.779860844
12.9994715725   10541.499375969 9471.012935496
13  10529.066751163 6233.173950593
13.000528234    10583.146089496 7356.552861198
13.5846102372   14401.37205005  8704.617585743
13.5849625007   14363.974258746 8713.01377627
13.5853146782   14282.311931098 10376.784988679
13.9997358105   17924.32579547  10960.299110444
14  18539.802353817 10978.068437467
14.0002641412   17573.649107848 12459.412789012
14.5847863797   22813.544369689 18111.530868468
14.5849625007   23197.178627511 15523.929346838
14.5851386002   24072.748522204 14975.096833361
14.9998679113   27122.227913974 22139.146166433
15  28343.29998547  20174.984879434
15.0001320766   27102.259759124 22299.988561706
15.5848744429   33093.457918842 24583.590207991
15.5849625007   37503.657556209 24067.295665602
15.5850505532   35029.522698607 21385.294903538
15.9999339572   35965.052986014 22156.773973963
16  36280.521720143 22768.653369153
16.0000660398   35824.858992535 22095.615170307
16.5849184725   39663.885952713 31544.055792361
16.5849625007   39702.343473768 32020.413157657
16.5850065276   39648.969347573 28171.132563909
16.999966979    39892.031287074 29686.823448866
17  39989.357985912 29563.339750158
17.0000330203   39881.838316571 29597.736848209
17.5849404868   39775.794203249 31879.906514408
17.5849625007   40090.939326761 42632.564123951
17.5849845143   39931.689963714 31764.349460218
17.9999834896   42059.054279617 33266.028653703
18  42036.328865752 33289.438190973
18.0000165102   41612.020018579 33235.604391119
18.5849514938   43934.287383115 34805.978837333
18.5849625007   43757.423406646 34775.082842428
18.5849735076   43806.569286575 34868.32660189
18.9999917448   41188.289875588 35271.795693727
19  41493.55703896  34852.366230723
19.0000082551   41261.894071401 34783.859418754
19.5849569973   46750.487759933 34134.247276319
19.5849625007   46742.858105665 34030.893356802
19.5849680042   46272.488727414 34022.599544173
19.9999958724   39361.483527363 32070.098342443
20  39011.235342666 32078.172520878
20.0000041276   39417.359046151 38439.343773152
20.584959749    32541.918497241 33797.506118382
20.5849625007   32994.871611205 33265.916556813
20.5849652524   33282.976976094 33338.510640811
20.9999979362   30617.072384717 36638.090297614
21  30363.559637657 30035.390170359
21.0000020638   30904.87103504  36802.61117229
21.5849611249   32602.98950649  29047.077888273
21.5849625007   32565.912266974 27241.537806327
21.5849638766   32245.756882312 25122.081310011
21.9999989681   34631.731967715 29207.946376923
22  34818.087121474 26740.547005968
22.0000010319   34592.778882135 23472.260927074
22.5849618128   36725.131366442 24061.012240664
22.5849625007   37169.700021537 24183.159975874
22.5849631887   36395.704815157 25024.525623474
22.9999994841   38375.918718521 26704.848945865
23  37520.785869843 31543.462669175
23.0000005159   38196.313421571 24765.815374737
23.5849621568   39862.547608764 24697.332265871
23.5849625007   39566.218535168 24819.606183673
23.5849628447   40324.827504458 24693.315933731
23.999999742    40827.102556167 25069.671590142
24  40424.324710132 30577.659465717
24.000000258    40358.89294868  24941.099097069
24.5849623287   41435.360383826 31862.436201921
24.5849625007   40956.508539929 28507.061514714
24.5849626727   41644.67545765  27605.865978166
24.999999871    42239.781170468 26207.879591305
25  41752.769862369 25473.326348502
25.000000129    41613.905092199 25261.482217836
25.5849624147   42649.518306265 30801.895171737
25.5849625007   42414.091666634 25250.400756266
25.5849625867   43194.093893614 25250.152249501
25.9999999355   42879.187112688 25235.946710162
26  44507.168450242 25306.504292221
26.0000000645   43992.340356826 25344.246828366
}\datatable
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width= 1\columnwidth,
height=4cm,
xlabel={Message Size},
ylabel={Gbps},
%y label style={pos=east},
y label style={at={(0.1, 0.5)}},
x label style={at={(0.5, 0.08)}},
legend pos=north west,
legend style={anchor=north west,font=\tiny},
xtick={0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26},
%xmode=log,
%log basis x={2},
scaled y ticks = false,
y tick label style={
    /pgf/number format/1000 sep = \thinspace
},
x tick label style={font=\tiny},
scaled x ticks=manual:{}{%
    \pgfmathparse{ (#1 < 10) ? pow(2,#1) : ((#1 < 20) ? pow(2, #1 - 10):pow(2, #1 - 20))}%
},
xticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber\tick },
scaled y ticks=manual:{}{%
        \pgfmathparse{#1/1000}%
},
yticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber\tick},
]
    \addplot [mark=+,color=black] table[y={Shared Memory}, x = {Data Size}] {\datatable};
    \addlegendentry{Shared Memory}[minimum height=1.9in];
    \addplot [mark=none,color=gray] table[y={NIO}, x ={Data Size}] {\datatable};
    \addlegendentry{NIO}[minimum height=1.9in];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result is:
[image]
However, I want a small modification in the x-axis. Instead of

{1,4,16,64,256,1,4,16,64,256,1,4,16,64}

I would like
{1,4,16,64,256,1Kb,4Kb,16Kb,64Kb,256Kb,1Mb,4Mb,16Mb,64Mb}

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @BenediktBauer Done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would set the `xticklabels` explicit and rotate them. And I think it is better to use the same size for all `ticklabels`.

```
\documentclass{paper}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\pgfplotstableread{
{Data Size}    {Shared Memory}   {NIO}
  ...
}\datatable
\begin{document}

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    width=\columnwidth,
    height=4cm,
    legend pos=north west,
    legend style={anchor=north west,font=\scriptsize},
    %
    tick label style={font=\scriptsize},
    %
    xlabel={Message Size},
    xtick={0,2,...,26},
    x tick label style={rotate=90},
    xticklabels={
      1\,b,4\,b,16\,b,64\,b,256\,b,
      1\,Kb,4\,Kb,16\,Kb,64\,Kb,256\,Kb,
      1\,Mb,4\,Mb,16\,Mb,64\,Mb
    },
    %
    ylabel={Gbps},
    scaled y ticks=manual:{}{\pgfmathparse{#1/1000}},
  ]

    \addplot [mark=+,color=black] table[y={Shared Memory}, x = {Data Size}] {\datatable};
    \addlegendentry{Shared Memory}[minimum height=1.9in];
    \addplot [mark=none,color=gray] table[y={NIO}, x ={Data Size}] {\datatable};
    \addlegendentry{NIO}[minimum height=1.9in];
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: After two hours I came with something equivalent but more complicated

Answer (score 2):

REVISED to use full MWE provided by OP. What I did was  add notations where I think it makes sense.  I added these notations as part of the x-label.  I think it looks better to label below the numbers rather than to label the numbers themselves.

If you change the scale of your graph, the dimensions `\cyclewidth` and `\loffset` will need to be revised.

Note: I changed the plot width to better conform to your picture.

```
\documentclass{paper}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[pdftex]{color}

\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shadows,patterns}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{dblfloatfix}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\pgfplotstableread{
{Data Size}    {Shared Memory}   {NIO}
0   1.510618995 1.211303577
1   3.2303486   2.284973183
1.5849625007    4.856564878 3.650475913
2   6.477938316 4.413739735
2.5849625007    9.712070412 7.308872177
3   12.931555487    8.820402778
3.5849625007    19.484353638    12.822872274
3.7004397181    21.122457882    14.851562274
4   25.912743129    18.621127822
4.2479275134    30.729567163    22.179711705
4.3923174228    34.29160211 19.027447421
4.5849625007    38.244025295    29.328904007
4.7548875022    43.959939412    32.568470093
4.8579809951    46.929519191    34.986339417
5   52.492719706    39.106509783
5.1292830169    58.46781981 31.501307665
5.4918530963    73.543666985    43.323522934
5.5849625007    77.459322667    48.490743999
5.672425342 82.985235817    56.872079534
5.9307373376    99.796973815    54.818062952
6   102.283900308   57.550038602
6.0660891905    108.375577493   60.505008949
6.5391588111    148.767633673   83.800438008
6.5849625007    152.995602336   106.139907555
6.6293566201    160.628615581   89.067641012
6.9657842847    200.161297725   112.453472776
7   205.824015933   135.930753075
7.0334230015    210.192513373   116.697242107
7.5622424242    304.035778887   168.699330324
7.5849625007    305.748875502   178.617329882
7.6073303137    314.050317173   223.004631634
7.9829935747    401.791173697   304.945579899
8   409.483432748   303.157529871
8.0168082877    424.119265186   231.545405236
8.5736471875    605.448555176   424.80696054
8.5849625007    607.284603452   342.123641214
8.5961897561    615.863754668   395.555755955
8.9915218461    803.207926285   611.575583119
9   812.506013352   553.18025024
9.0084286221    815.09008592    578.762145252
9.5793159376    1210.628898233  925.793618042
9.5849625007    1209.223171089  683.90157147
9.5905870499    1219.631198049  893.794979677
9.9957671509    1596.264405994  1103.914749616
10  1606.587640249  1085.280140642
10.0042204663   1616.864825222  1130.343164423
10.5821419817   2345.139190349  1528.461298638
10.5849625007   2403.540379252  1430.78942209
10.5877775163   2366.704676255  1456.155914263
10.9978851278   3076.509079427  1803.067395975
11  3078.925940461  1746.102644706
11.0021117765   3111.258074768  1994.433990999
11.5835529305   4556.56852076   3058.174009469
11.5849625007   4502.975871005  2551.424401063
11.5863706951   4538.094725282  2533.045417625
11.9989429514   5827.952659919  4983.721139081
12  5812.588729177  3774.507385952
12.0010562746   5853.675269234  4017.979668263
12.5842578877   8386.555402598  4910.603339731
12.5849625007   8332.804968689  4966.990490482
12.5856667697   8392.878076465  5048.779860844
12.9994715725   10541.499375969 9471.012935496
13  10529.066751163 6233.173950593
13.000528234    10583.146089496 7356.552861198
13.5846102372   14401.37205005  8704.617585743
13.5849625007   14363.974258746 8713.01377627
13.5853146782   14282.311931098 10376.784988679
13.9997358105   17924.32579547  10960.299110444
14  18539.802353817 10978.068437467
14.0002641412   17573.649107848 12459.412789012
14.5847863797   22813.544369689 18111.530868468
14.5849625007   23197.178627511 15523.929346838
14.5851386002   24072.748522204 14975.096833361
14.9998679113   27122.227913974 22139.146166433
15  28343.29998547  20174.984879434
15.0001320766   27102.259759124 22299.988561706
15.5848744429   33093.457918842 24583.590207991
15.5849625007   37503.657556209 24067.295665602
15.5850505532   35029.522698607 21385.294903538
15.9999339572   35965.052986014 22156.773973963
16  36280.521720143 22768.653369153
16.0000660398   35824.858992535 22095.615170307
16.5849184725   39663.885952713 31544.055792361
16.5849625007   39702.343473768 32020.413157657
16.5850065276   39648.969347573 28171.132563909
16.999966979    39892.031287074 29686.823448866
17  39989.357985912 29563.339750158
17.0000330203   39881.838316571 29597.736848209
17.5849404868   39775.794203249 31879.906514408
17.5849625007   40090.939326761 42632.564123951
17.5849845143   39931.689963714 31764.349460218
17.9999834896   42059.054279617 33266.028653703
18  42036.328865752 33289.438190973
18.0000165102   41612.020018579 33235.604391119
18.5849514938   43934.287383115 34805.978837333
18.5849625007   43757.423406646 34775.082842428
18.5849735076   43806.569286575 34868.32660189
18.9999917448   41188.289875588 35271.795693727
19  41493.55703896  34852.366230723
19.0000082551   41261.894071401 34783.859418754
19.5849569973   46750.487759933 34134.247276319
19.5849625007   46742.858105665 34030.893356802
19.5849680042   46272.488727414 34022.599544173
19.9999958724   39361.483527363 32070.098342443
20  39011.235342666 32078.172520878
20.0000041276   39417.359046151 38439.343773152
20.584959749    32541.918497241 33797.506118382
20.5849625007   32994.871611205 33265.916556813
20.5849652524   33282.976976094 33338.510640811
20.9999979362   30617.072384717 36638.090297614
21  30363.559637657 30035.390170359
21.0000020638   30904.87103504  36802.61117229
21.5849611249   32602.98950649  29047.077888273
21.5849625007   32565.912266974 27241.537806327
21.5849638766   32245.756882312 25122.081310011
21.9999989681   34631.731967715 29207.946376923
22  34818.087121474 26740.547005968
22.0000010319   34592.778882135 23472.260927074
22.5849618128   36725.131366442 24061.012240664
22.5849625007   37169.700021537 24183.159975874
22.5849631887   36395.704815157 25024.525623474
22.9999994841   38375.918718521 26704.848945865
23  37520.785869843 31543.462669175
23.0000005159   38196.313421571 24765.815374737
23.5849621568   39862.547608764 24697.332265871
23.5849625007   39566.218535168 24819.606183673
23.5849628447   40324.827504458 24693.315933731
23.999999742    40827.102556167 25069.671590142
24  40424.324710132 30577.659465717
24.000000258    40358.89294868  24941.099097069
24.5849623287   41435.360383826 31862.436201921
24.5849625007   40956.508539929 28507.061514714
24.5849626727   41644.67545765  27605.865978166
24.999999871    42239.781170468 26207.879591305
25  41752.769862369 25473.326348502
25.000000129    41613.905092199 25261.482217836
25.5849624147   42649.518306265 30801.895171737
25.5849625007   42414.091666634 25250.400756266
25.5849625867   43194.093893614 25250.152249501
25.9999999355   42879.187112688 25235.946710162
26  44507.168450242 25306.504292221
26.0000000645   43992.340356826 25344.246828366
}\datatable
\def\cyclewidth{1.82cm}
\def\loffset{0.6cm}
\begin{document}
{\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width= .6\columnwidth,
height=4cm,
xlabel={\stackon[6pt]{Message Size}
{\tiny\sffamily\hspace{\loffset}\smash{\rule{.4pt}{3ex}}%
  \makebox[\cyclewidth]{bytes}\smash{\rule{.4pt}{3ex}}%
  \makebox[\cyclewidth]{kb}\smash{\rule{.4pt}{3ex}}%
  \makebox[\cyclewidth]{Mb}}},
ylabel={Gbps},
%y label style={pos=east},
y label style={at={(0.1, 0.5)}},
x label style={at={(0.5, 0.08)}},
legend pos=north west,
legend style={anchor=north west,font=\tiny},
xtick={0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26},
%xmode=log,
%log basis x={2},
scaled y ticks = false,
y tick label style={
    /pgf/number format/1000 sep = \thinspace
},
x tick label style={font=\tiny},
scaled x ticks=manual:{}{%
    \pgfmathparse{ (#1 < 10) ? pow(2,#1) : ((#1 < 20) ? pow(2, #1 - 10):pow(2, #1 - 20))}%
},
xticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber\tick },
scaled y ticks=manual:{}{%
        \pgfmathparse{#1/1000}%
},
yticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber\tick},
]
    \addplot [mark=+,color=black] table[y={Shared Memory}, x = {Data Size}] {\datatable};
    \addlegendentry{Shared Memory}[minimum height=1.9in];
    \addplot [mark=none,color=gray] table[y={NIO}, x ={Data Size}] {\datatable};
    \addlegendentry{NIO}[minimum height=1.9in];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\par}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am compiling in a Linux box. What problem do you have to compile?

Comment: @IntiGonzalez-Herrera I had a copy error.  Resolved, and aI have revised my answer.